# how to determine CPU cache size in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I would like to know if there is a way to determine CPU cache size in managed code?

I am writing a Strassen's algorithm for matrix multiplication in C# and would like to know how many elements of the matrices I could fit into cache to improve computational speed.

Comment: I don't think you can do it in a managed fashion. Going to have to use WMI.

Comment: ...WMI has a managed API though?

Comment: @Kieren: Yes, via a COM Interop. I am not sure if this is what the OP means when he says "managed".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use WMI to retrieve cache information.

You will first need to add a reference to `System.Management.dll` to your project, then you can use the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;

namespace Scratch
{
    public enum CacheLevel : ushort 
    {
        Level1 = 3,
        Level2 = 4,
        Level3 = 5,
    }

    public static class CPUInfo
    {
        public static List<uint> GetCacheSizes(CacheLevel level)
        {
            ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_CacheMemory");
            ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
            List<uint> cacheSizes = new List<uint>(moc.Count);

            cacheSizes.AddRange(moc
              .Cast<ManagementObject>()
              .Where(p => (ushort)(p.Properties["Level"].Value) == (ushort)level)
              .Select(p => (uint)(p.Properties["MaxCacheSize"].Value)));

            return cacheSizes;
        }
    }
}
```

Full details of the `Win32_CacheMemory` WMI class is available at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394080(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll look through WMI.

Comment: @GKalnytskyi Hope it helps. The above code gives info about *all* cache levels including level 1, which the other `Win32_Processor` answers do not.

Comment: Thank you for answering the freaking question rather than the first hit in google on SO where the accepted answer was "Why do you need that?"  That is literally the most annoying tic on this site.

Answer (score 2):

is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373%28VS.85%29.aspx) what you are looking for? The Win32_Processor class features L2CacheSize and L3CacheSize members.

Comment: Bummer, he wants to know level 1 cache.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will look at WMI in more detail. I just thought that there is a pure managed solution that I couldn't find.

Answer (score 2):

```
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    class Processor
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

        //[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        //public static extern int GetCurrentProcessorNumber();

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
        private struct GROUP_AFFINITY
        {
            public UIntPtr Mask;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
            public ushort Group;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U2)]
            public ushort[] Reserved;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern Boolean SetThreadGroupAffinity(IntPtr hThread, ref GROUP_AFFINITY GroupAffinity, ref GROUP_AFFINITY PreviousGroupAffinity);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct PROCESSORCORE
        {
            public byte Flags;
        };

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct NUMANODE
        {
            public uint NodeNumber;
        }

        public enum PROCESSOR_CACHE_TYPE
        {
            CacheUnified,
            CacheInstruction,
            CacheData,
            CacheTrace
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CACHE_DESCRIPTOR
        {
            public byte Level;
            public byte Associativity;
            public ushort LineSize;
            public uint Size;
            public PROCESSOR_CACHE_TYPE Type;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_UNION
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public PROCESSORCORE ProcessorCore;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public NUMANODE NumaNode;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public CACHE_DESCRIPTOR Cache;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            private UInt64 Reserved1;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            private UInt64 Reserved2;
        }

        public enum LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_RELATIONSHIP
        {
            RelationProcessorCore,
            RelationNumaNode,
            RelationCache,
            RelationProcessorPackage,
            RelationGroup,
            RelationAll = 0xffff
        }

        public struct SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION
        {
#pragma warning disable 0649
            public UIntPtr ProcessorMask;
            public LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_RELATIONSHIP Relationship;
            public SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_UNION ProcessorInformation;
#pragma warning restore 0649
        }

        [DllImport(@"kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool GetLogicalProcessorInformation(IntPtr Buffer, ref uint ReturnLength);

        private const int ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;

        private static SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION[] _logicalProcessorInformation = null;

        public static SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION[] LogicalProcessorInformation
        {
            get
            {
                if (_logicalProcessorInformation != null)
                    return _logicalProcessorInformation;

                uint ReturnLength = 0;

                GetLogicalProcessorInformation(IntPtr.Zero, ref ReturnLength);

                if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
                {
                    IntPtr Ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)ReturnLength);
                    try
                    {
                        if (GetLogicalProcessorInformation(Ptr, ref ReturnLength))
                        {
                            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION));
                            int len = (int)ReturnLength / size;
                            _logicalProcessorInformation = new SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION[len];
                            IntPtr Item = Ptr;

                            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                            {
                                _logicalProcessorInformation[i] = (SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(Item, typeof(SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION));
                                Item += size;
                            }

                            return _logicalProcessorInformation;
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Ptr);
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Handy helper function:

```
public static void GetPerCoreCacheSizes(out Int64  L1, out Int64 L2, out Int64 L3)
{
    L1 = 0;
    L2 = 0;
    L3 = 0;

    var info = Processor.LogicalProcessorInformation;
    foreach (var entry in info)
    {
        if (entry.Relationship != Processor.LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_RELATIONSHIP.RelationCache)
            continue;
        Int64 mask = (Int64)entry.ProcessorMask;
        if ((mask & (Int64)1) == 0)
            continue;
        var cache = entry.ProcessorInformation.Cache;
        switch (cache.Level)
        {
            case 1: L1 = L1 + cache.Size; break;
            case 2: L2 = L2 + cache.Size; break;
            case 3: L3 = L3 + cache.Size; break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

And call it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    long l1, l2, l3;

    GetPerCoreCacheSizes(out l1, out l2, out l3);

    String s = String.Format("Single-core memory cache: L1={0} KB, L2={1} KB, L3={2} KB", l1 / 1024, l2 / 1024, l3 / 1024);
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Output**:

```
Single-core memory cache: L1=64 KB, L2=256 KB, L3=6144 KB
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
using System.Management;

uint32 cachsize;
public void CPUSpeed()
{
  using(ManagementObject Mo = new ManagementObject("Win32_Processor.DeviceID='CPU0'"))
  {
    cachsize = (uint)(Mo["L2CacheSize"]);
  }
}
```

I get it from [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank's! I'll look through WMI