# Determining Cache Size

Tags: c#

Is there a way to determine the optimal cache size (L1 and L2 possibly) within C#?  I'm asking this because formally worked with: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_tiling Loop Tiling to make sure large data (for example Matrix Multiplications of like [3000] by [3000].

Currently I just ran multiple tests per computer, increasing block size, and grabbed the optimal cache that way but I am looking for a much faster run time calculator, or API, or something to help me determine this within C#.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to determine CPU cache size in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995787/how-to-determine-cpu-cache-size-in-net)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

AFAIK, C# is not a language that cares about such low-level questions. .Net Framework and the underlying OS should take care of that. It's not your problem as a .Net programmer.

If you DO want to know, you'll have to use/write a function/library in some lower level language like C/C++ ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794632/programmatically-get-the-cache-line-size))

Comment: I was using C# for the parallel processing mainly.  I know how to do it a little bit in C but felt a lot better about doing it in C#.  I could always cheat a little bit and write something in C or C++ to output it and read it into C# couldn't i?

Comment: That's what I meant. Also if you check that link I gave, in Linux you can grab the cache from *sys*, although I don't think this interests you at all :)

Comment: Yeah I saw that; then I traced it to the Windows Version and I could base it from it.  Thank you :) Marking as answered.

Comment: I'm sorry, but C# has pointers and explicit struct layouts and SIMD primitives.  Of COURSE C# cares about this stuff.  This isn't Java.

Comment: @hoodaticus Hence the AFAIK ;)