# Actual number of bytes in CPU Cache from WMI

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995787/how-to-determine-cpu-cache-size-in-net) shows how to get the cache size from the Windows Management Object

Let's say for `MaxCacheSize`, the number I get back is **512**. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394080(v=vs.85).aspx) says it returns kilobytes. Do they mean exactly **512,000** bytes, or should I extrapolate this to mean **524,288**?

Comment: Unless explicitly indicated otherwise, memory sizes use binary prefixes, so a kilobyte of memory is always 1024 bytes.

Comment: In computing, the only time "kilo-" *doesn't* mean 1024 is in marketing and packaging materials.  Hard drive manufacturers tend to use the prefix to mean 1000 for the layperson, for instance.

Comment: @Amy & JeroenMostert these sound like answers. Also, I am trying not to assume about this specific class... you know what they say about assuming...

Comment: @Amy: that's a popular theory, but not quite right. 1 kbps is 1000 bits per second, even when your network cable is connected to a computer. Network professionals don't much care about what computer programmers invented one day either. Despite what we like to think, it really is the programmers who messed this one up just because someone saw that 1024 was awfully close to 1000.

Comment: @JeroenMostert hm, very interesting

Comment: TheCatWhisperer: you're right not to assume in the sense that the WMI classes do occasionally return wrong/weird results based on the documentation (like stating "Pages" when the result is actually in bytes), but it's a *very* safe bet that the CPU cache size is a power of two, by virtue of how addressing works. A cache size that's not a power of two would be either inefficient or wasteful. @Amy: the [WP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) has way more background info than you probably want to know. :-)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Please post your previous comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, unless explicitly indicated otherwise, memory sizes use binary prefixes, so a kilobyte of memory (main or cache) is 1024 bytes, not 1000. The size of the cache is typically not the size of the memory chips used to implement the cache, but the amount of main memory the cache can cache, so it simply follows the policy of main memory addressing conventions. (The cache itself is physically bigger, due to bookkeeping overhead.)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) has an extensive article on the history behind this convention and also notes "capacities of main memory and cache memory are usually expressed with customary binary prefixes".

By sheer coincidence, 512 000 bytes is precisely 500 KiB, a doubly round number. Even so, a `MaxCacheSize` value of "512 kilobytes" is certainly 524 288 bytes (512 KiB).